# How to get IP address in node.js

Tags: node.js, server, ip

How in node.js I can get the IP adress of my server?

I need know this ip for conection with my server, but I dont know where I can see this ip adress(

Comment: Where are you running it? If it is a server then server's ip and if it is on your computer then your computer's ip.

Comment: What OS is your server running on?

Comment: I`m running on my computer, I have Windows 8.1(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, go to console window and type `ipconfig`.  You should get a listing that will have a section like this in it:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7533:a40e:4362:5c49%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7      <=== This is it
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

That is the IP address of your computer on your local LAN and can be used to reach it from within your local LAN.

This a dynamically assigned IP address.  It can change from time to time, though will typically stay the same for long periods of time.

---

If you want to reach it from the internet, that is more complicated as you will need the public IP address of your internet connection and will need to set up port forwarding in your router.

Comment: 'and will need to set up port forwarding in your router.' where I can read more about how do this?

Comment: @AnastasiaSisordia - A google search for "port forwarding" to explain what it is and your router's users interface/help system to show you how to configure your specific router.  You can see what your public IP address of your router is by just going to a site like this: http://www.whatismypublicip.com/.  Note, before opening your your server to the outside internet, you better make darn sure you've done security properly on your web server, because it will be open to attackers as soon as you set up the port forwarding.